# Частичное отсутствие перевода на странице выдвижения кандидатов

Tags: дефект, локализация, выборы

Частично отсутствует перевод на [странице выдвижения кандидатов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=nomination):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16297
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17175

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая 2023.4.5.43377